# Outlook MailItem Body sometimes become unreadable

Tags: outlook, com, vsto, outlook-addin

When I use COM API to get the Body of MailItem Object on some Japanese environment Outlook client, sometimes the content of Body would be unreadable. And it shows that, Outlook sends the content string to COM component by ANSI encoding (Shift-JIS), but COM API expected Unicode (2-bytes length) encoding and the mail body really is encoding by Unicode when I view the source of the mail. After I restart the Outlook client, the problem just could not be reproduced on the same email. Why does Outlook sometimes convert the encoding of email body to ANSI, and most of time not ?

Also when Outlook convert the Unicode content to ANSI (It should not be, as the mail source is Unicode encoding) and send it back to COM invoker, the Body of MailItem shows some html elements, is it a bug of Outlook?

Comment: Are you sure this is for a MailItem, not a ReportItem object?

Comment: Sure, I use the exact COM API MailItem.Body

Comment: What is the Outlook version? Is that a PST store or an Exchange mailbox?

Comment: The version is Outlook 2016 (16.0.4549.1000) 32-bit, and it's an Exchange mailbox.